# Set row color of Telerik RadGrid

Tags: c#, telerik, radgrid

I am using a RadGrid for displaying the data from a database. I want to change the row color in the RadGrid to red if in the status column that row shows as "REJECTED". If the status is NULL then the row will remain displaying as the color white. I have tried this code but the row still does not change the color to red.

```
try
{
    if (dataBoundItem["status"].Text == "REJECTED")
    {
        TableCell cell = (TableCell)dataBoundItem["status"];
        cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        dataBoundItem.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

        if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
        {
            GridDataItem dataBoundItem1 = e.Item as GridDataItem;

            if (dataBoundItem1["Status"].Text != null)
            {
                cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                dataBoundItem1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                dataBoundItem1["status"].ForeColor = Color.Red;
                dataBoundItem1["status"].Font.Bold = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
catch
{ }
```

Comment: Can you please provide radgrid mark up code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
using System.Drawing;
 
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
 {
  if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
     GridDataItem dataBoundItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;
     TableCell celltoVerify1 = dataBoundItem["status"];
       if (celltoVerify1.Text== "REJECTED")
        {
            celltoVerify1.ForeColor =  Color.Red;/// Only Change Cell Color
            dataBoundItem.ForeColor = Color.Yellow; /// Change the row Color
            //celltoVerify1.Font.Bold = true;
            //celltoVerify1.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
    }
 }
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hi, may i know what is dataBoundItem mean ?  is RadGrid ID ?

Comment: @GohHan "dataBoundItem" is used to get the distance of the right type